# Распараллеливание списка

Tags: c#, async-await

Добрый день. У меня возникла следующая задача: я получаю список строк, после этого создаю экземпляр класса и вызываю в нём метод. На данный момент нужно сделать распараллеливание этого списка, то есть, обработка в разных потоках. Одновременно может выполняться определённое количество потоков. Как только один закончил - запускается следующий, и так до самого конца. Я бы сделал на `Parallel.Foreach`, но проблема в том, что нужно сделать именно на `async/await`. Информацию по ним я находил, но понять, как с ними работать, до конца не могу, ибо мне проще понимать чтением кода. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Странные у вас требования. Если у вас есть жёсткое ограничение на количество потоков, откуда вдруг взялся async/await? Async/await не даёт вам контроля над потоками, это более высокоуровневый метод.

Comment: Хорошо, если его нет, то как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, должно сработать такое.

```
async Task ProcessTasks(IEnumerable<string> data, int maxParallelTasks)
{
    var runningTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
    foreach (var s in data) // цикл по всем строкам
    {
        // дождёмся, когда найдётся «место» для нового задания
        while (runningTasks.Count >= maxParallelTasks)
        {
            // дождёмся окончания задания
            var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(runningTasks);
            await firstFinishedTask; // доставим возможное исключение сюда
            runningTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);
        }
        // стартуем новое задание
        runningTasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessData(s));
    }
    // дождёмся окончания всех запущенных заданий
    foreach (var task in runningTasks)
        await task;
}
```

---

Если отбросить жёсткое ограничение на количество одновременных заданий, и доверить планировку выполнения TPL, подойдёт более простой код:

```
var tasks = data.Select(s => Task.Run(() => ProcessData(s))).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, теперь всё ясно.

Comment: @DmitryPopov: Пожалуйста!